# Sanitizing Integer Database Input

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application that takes data via a POST request. I am using this data to insert a new row into the database. I know that using `mysql_real_escape_string()` (plus removing % and _) is the way to go for strings, but what about integer values? Right now, I am using the PHP function `intval()` on them.

However, I wanted to make sure that `intval()` is perfectly safe. I can't see a way of an attacker preforming a SQL injection attack when the variables are run through `intval()` first (since it always returns an integer), but I wanted to make sure this is the case from people that have more experience than I.

Thanks.

Comment: Heads up: If you're dealing with numbers larger than 32 or 64 bits (depending on your platform) `intval()` will return zero.  This is obviously undesirable if you're attempting to store very large numbers in your database.  For example, facebook's ids haven't fit in 32 bits for years http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/45

Comment: @Frank Farmer: Hm.. that's interesting. Thanks for the heads up. I'll look into what we can do to solve that problem, if it is needed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, `intval()` is safe. There is absolutely no way to perform an SQL injection when the parameter is converted to integer, because (obviously) the format of an integer does not allow putting SQL keywords (or quotes, or whatever) in it.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: You could also use `(int)$id` because casting is much faster than using the `intval($id)` function. Check: http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/php-casting-vs-intval/

Comment: Are you sure? Cause intval is a lot permissive on what it takes as an input parameter. This code produces correct integer results but I would never want such values inside my queries : 
`$var = "123TYPE_JUGGLING";
var_dump( is_numeric($var));
var_dump( (int)$var); var_dump(intval($var));`

Comment: intval always return int, why would you not?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to prevent SQL injection is to always use prepared statments. Use the mysqli libraries or better yet an ORM such as doctrine etc.

Your queries then become something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prep_stmt("select * from .... where userid = ? and username = ?");

/* Binding 2 parameters. */
$stmt->bind_param("is", $userid, $username);

$userid = 15;
$username = "don";

/* Executing the statement */
$stmt->execute( ) or die ("Could not execute statement");
```

Comment: +1 for prepared statements.  However, I'd still validate the user-input data prior to executing an insert in order to avoid a SQL exception.  Unless, of course, the ORM or framework was doing that for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, prepared statements are not available for this particular project.

Answer (score 2):

I always do

```
$var = (int)$_POST['var'];
```

to make sure $var is handled as an integer in all circumstances, and never look at $_POST['var'] again. Looking at the manual, intval() does exactly the same.

Whichever way you go, in subsequence $var will be an actual integer, which is quite safe to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statment is best way to deal sql injection.
or use PDO
otherwise, intval is better than is_numeric